# Can the number of people you reached decrease?

Tags: support

I was just wondering if the number of people you reached could decrease. Is it possible?

I'm asking this question, because I have first noticed that the number of people I reached was shown ~3k (I might be mistaken over here) and when I checked later, it  showed ~2k. Unless it was my mistake, could this possibly happen?

Comment: I would say this might happen if you reached quite a large number with one post and the post gets removed for some reason. Would I be right in assuming this?

Comment: maybe if the people you reached pass away I guess it is possible

Comment: @DDD4C4U Uhhhhh.. let's not get there .....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could be right, this could happen when a post has been deleted, but there might be another reason for this: an answer of yours used to be one of the top answers on a question, but due to downvotes, upvotes on a competing answer or an unaccept it doesn't qualify anymore for the 'people reached' formula, which is described here: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/295232).

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

View counts on individual posts never decrease.

Be aware that this number is just an *estimate*; it's roughly the number of

> **Views of pages where your helpful posts had some decent probability of being seen.**
>
> That doesn't mean we *know* the visitor scrolled to your post, or that your answer helped them - we simply don't track that.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking: If the user accepts the answer but later, if the post gets deleted by high-reps for whatever reason, I still reached a few people right?( Before the question was removed)

Comment: Yes, but just like reputation, deleted contributions don't count most of the time.